# Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion

Tags: vpn, installation, windows-registry

I was installing "Private Internet Access" and it refused to do so due to not being able to install TAP.
I tried to install a version manually and it used an old NordVPN version I had on my computer. This still didn't work.

So, I uninstalled that an am trying to install the V9 TAP adapter download from the official site.

When I try to do so I get the above message.

I did, of course, restart my computer between each stage.

Not sure where to go from here.
All searches I have made for that message have no connection to my case.